# Unity no longer able to build project

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, exception, build

I've been banging my head against the wall the last 6 days or so trying to get Unity to build my Android game.

My game used to build as it should a few months back, I had a couple new things I came up with and added those (the game runs fine within Unity, there are no errors in play mode).

Trying to build my game with the C++ compiler set to the 'master', however, consistently fails, with the following exceptions:

1.

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\fy9m9\libil2cpp.so failed with output:
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.14f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.gold.exe: internal error in arm_branch_common, at /buildbot/src/android/binutils/toolchain/binutils/binutils-2.27/gold/arm.cc:4063
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2. 

```
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <6a5b55f2e18b419e9faedac06ac6af94>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <6a5b55f2e18b419e9faedac06ac6af94>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <b5a1f7b6d39d4ca78ca284153b2ea92d>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <6a5b55f2e18b419e9faedac06ac6af94>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

3. 

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 668 seconds (667590 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

4. 

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <6a5b55f2e18b419e9faedac06ac6af94>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <6a5b55f2e18b419e9faedac06ac6af94>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Building with the C++ Compiler Configuration set to 'release' also compiles
- I can build the project if I switch the platform to Windows
- It seems the project can build if I set the compiler to 'debug' instead of 'master', this does not solve the problem, but might be a clue to the actual problem(?)
- Making sure it was not caused by something I added: I loaded up the backup of my game (version 1.0, which worked fine and is also published), but the backup can also no longer be build.
- Making sure the problem is not with Unity itself, I tried to do a build of a clean project. This works as expected.
- I updated all packages in my project
- I updated the Unity version my project uses to 2021.3.14f1 (which I also use for another Android project, which can be build with that version).
- Updated the Google Play Games for Unity Plugin (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) and accompanying code changes that were required
- Per response on Reddit, I made sure that no script uses the UnityEditor namespace (the few that do, are put with #IF UNITY_EDITOR commands

Comment: The cpp code is not compiling so everything else fails as shown in first error.  that has to get fixed.  The error message shows the line a source file where failure is occurring.  Can you post the line that is failing.  Make sure all the paths files still exist for first error.

Comment: Which file do you mean? I tried to follow the path mentioned in the exception but it leads to a folder with files that have random names and end with *.o as extension?

I tried searching the file 'arm.cc' but windows cannot find said file(?)

Comment: The o files are intermediate object files.  There is a o file for each source file.  Usually they are in a object folder.   At least one source file is getting build.  Than when linker attempts to create executables by combining the object files a object is missing (it didn't compile) and you get a failure.  The object files have same base name as the source.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly: There might be a script in my project that doesn't compile nicely causing my problem?

I did figure something odd just now, it seems Unity *can* build my project if I set the compiler to 'debug' instead of 'master' (not sure if this helps)

Comment: A project in the Bin folder has Debug and Release folders. It probably means a dll should automatically get moved into the Debug/Release folder when you compile.  Some people manually put the dll into the folder which creates issues when folder you use clean build which deletes these files.  The csproj file should have instructions to copy files into folder.  An instruction is probably missing.  I would compare the dll in Debug and Release and see if they are the same in main project and any child projects.

Comment: I decided to try something a little different. I switched my platform from android to windows and there it also initially failed to build, but with a usefull message. Apparantly the C++ modules from VS were not installed... Installed those and now it can build for Windows at least. I switched the platform back to Android, but there it still fails to build with the same error...

I did find a Debug folder at .\obj\Debug\, but there is no release folder.

Comment: You do not need the release version unless you publish.  Publish uses the release folder.  What is date of the debug build?  Want to check if it is new or old.  What is target? Not sure if this is Core issue or something else.  Try build Release version and see what happens.

Comment: I think you are on to something. The date on the files in the debug folder vary, the oldest being from 2020 (when I started the project) with various dates in between.

I switched the C++ compiler configuration to 'release' and that can also successfully build (yay!), but 'master' still doesn't work :/

Comment: Solve one issue at a time.  Start with : arm_branch_common, at /buildbot/src/android/binutils/toolchain/binutils/binutils-2.27/gold/arm.cc:4063

Comment: Thank you again for your time, it seems the issue is Unity specific as I finally managed to find someone else with the exact same problem: https://forum.unity.com/threads/fails-to-compile-on-android-arm-32.1135633/

It seems Unity's Android NDK version is out of date, meaning it'll likely be fixed if I use a more recent Unity version. Will give that a try and add an answer, so future people with the same problem know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I've had issues with Net Library running 32 bit mode would give Memory Errors and switching to 64 bit mode resolved issues.  Never found root cause of issue.  Things like this are not well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user jdweng I managed to find the problem by looking at it from a different angle. Which led me to a post on the Unity Forums with someone who has the exact same problem I described: https://forum.unity.com/threads/fails-to-compile-on-android-arm-32.1135633/

One user there mentions a solution (credits to pradotech), which ended up fixing the problem for me:

> I could build for Android using Master compiler after changing
> Stripping Level to Medium (I was using Low) and switching from .NET
> Framework to .NET Standard 2.1. Details below:
>
> - Unity 2021.3.9f1
> - Faster runtime
> - Compression: LZ4HC API
> - Compatibility: .NET Standard 2.1
> - Compiler Configuration: Master
> - All architectures (ARMv7, ARM64, x86 and x86-64)
> - Managed Stripping Level: Medium/High
> - I also removed some unused scripts from project.
>
> Build completed without any errors.
>
> Hope it keeps working and maybe that helps someone.

My project is using Unity 2021.3.14f1, I was already on .Net Standard 2.1.
I changed stripping to Medium, removed a *bunch* of deprecated scripts and now it works again.